# Unity3D Gui Sphere having distorted edges

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a make switch board with circular button.

For it i'm using Quad as a base and then overlaying 3D Spheres for the buttons.

For the texture of sphere's, I have made a Material to which a rectangular image is set.

in preview it looks good with all smooth edges, however, in game preview when I look closely at the sphere's their edges are distorted/pixelated.

Is there any restriction which should be adhered to make the sphere's have perfect smooth edges.

or I must be missing something.

[image: sphere with edge distortion]

Image uploaded. The Quad is of White color and there is a light source.

the texture was imported and overridden for platform for 2048.

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for [Unity Forums](http://forum.unity3d.com/forum.php) as it is not directly programming related.

Comment: I did posted there few days ago and didnt receive any response. and not quite sure if programming would be needed or not depending upon the solution. But happy to post it at other recommended space of the site for suitable audience.

Comment: can you please share the screen shot. And remember to make the "Max size" while importing image in unity to 2048

Comment: added image with 2048 size

Comment: Not sure if someone can confirm that it could be because of shader